# Is "strong medicine" idiomatic?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice, transatlantic-differences

Is the expression “strong medicine” idiomatic?

I am referring to drugs that contain a high concentration of chemicals and are used  for soothing severe pains or treating severe diseases. A drug whose dosage of chemicals is higher compared to your average [over-the-counter drugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Over-the-counter_drug).

Can I say the following:

> 1. You need some strong medicine to take away the pain
> 2. I want to ask my doctor for some strong medicine

Is there perhaps a more idiomatic expression used in the US or in the UK?

Comment: It is a well-known metaphor meaning something that is quite effective but very possibly upsetting or unpleasant if "taken".  For instance, an government economic policy may be described as "strong medicine" if it will supposedly "fix", say, unemployment, but will also cause incomes to drop.

Comment: So according to what you said, there is not a term for describing this kind of medicine , right?

Comment: Any metaphoric idiom can be used in its literal form (if the literal form makes any sense).  One needs to be a little careful in its use, though, to assure that it's properly understood.

Comment: Please give us an example of how you wish to use the phrase in a sentence about medicine. Then we have something to work with.

Comment: "Prescription medications" tend to be stronger (and are certainly more regulated) than "over the counter medications" if that is the goal.

Comment: I mean a high dose drug or medicine. A drug whose dose of chemicals is higher compared to ordinary drugs .

Comment: And I must add an example: a citalopram 20 mg tablet is weaker than a citalopram 50 mg one. ( citalopram is a drug for treating depression)

Comment: Perhaps "more/less efficient "?

Comment: A higher dose drug might be called a "stronger formula" or some such.  Only terms very much similar to the "strong medicine" idiom would be taken to imply the idiomatic meaning.

Comment: **Strong Poison** http://www.gutenberg.ca/ebooks/sayersdl-strongpoison/sayersdl-strongpoison-00-h.html

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit. I've fleshed out the question a bit more, and included two examples using the expression "strong medicine", but if you disapprove, please rollback your question to it previous version. (I see you are still active on EL&U) See also [Chasly from UK's](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282845/is-strong-medicine-idiomatic#comment628375_282845) comment

Comment: 'You need some strong painkillers to take away the pain'
'I want to ask my doctor for something stronger' are more idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

In Pharmacology, they use the noun [*potency*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potency_(pharmacology)) which is

> a measure of drug activity expressed in terms of the amount required to
>   produce an effect of given intensity. A **highly potent** drug (e.g.,
>   fentanyl, alprazolam, risperidone) evokes a larger response at low
>   concentrations, while a drug of **lower potency** (codiene, diazepam,
>   ziprasidone) evokes a small response at low concentrations. It is
>   proportional to affinity and efficacy.

Therefore, it would be more idiomatic and understandable if you say *(highly) potent drug/medicine* than *strong drug/medicine*.

[*Powerful*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=powerful+drug%2C+strong+drug&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpowerful%20drug%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrong%20drug%3B%2Cc0) could be a better alternative to *strong* in your context.

[Wiktionary, Ngram Viewer]

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking ways to identify strong medication for alleviating pain and not something that would imply another meaning, may I suggest the word 'narcotic'. Heavy duty narcotic for a bit more emphasis. For disease in general perhaps "potent remedy" would be one way to describe such medicine.
I hope one of those will work for you.

Comment: "Narcotic" defines a specific set of chemical characteristics.  Even some fairly strong pain relievers are not "narcotics", and there are many psychoactive drugs that are not "narcotics".

Comment: Yes, thank you. I understand that, but my answer was in response to this part of the question:  'I mean drugs which are used for soothing severe pains or treating severe diseases?
and it contains a high concentration of chemicals'.  Would my other suggestion suffice as a possible solution? How do you feel about 'potent remedy' or even 'potent medicine' as the word potent may not be as idiomatic as the word 'strong'.

Comment: Perhaps keramus would be most able to determine whether or not my suggestion(s) are useful as he or she did not mention specifically in what context this 'strong medicine' phrase would be used.